# Run different test cases on 4 remote machines with selenium

Tags: selenium, grid

I have 20 test cases, i want to run the first 5 on one remote machine, the other five test cases on the other remote machine....that means run the 20 test cases on 4 different remote machines.

i am using selenium 2.0 webdriver. please tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

What test framework are you using? Although Selenium Grid gives you the ability to run remotely, it is the test framework which provides the mechanism to run in parallel.

Some of the frameworks which support this includes;

Parallel-Test (Ruby) - supports Rspec, Cucumber and TestUnit
TestNG (Java)
JUnit (Java) - I haven't tried it myself as I have always used TestNG in Java
MbUnit (C#)

There may be others